# Php how to check for duplicate results?

Tags: php

Hi I'm currently querying from a database base user ids for a contest, However I want to avoid choosing duplicates in my results_array, this function getrandomspecies receives a array_result, this array results iterates 7 times. How test that I don't put duplicates in my results_array? I have gotten several duplicates.

```
    function getrandomspecies($array_result){

     //database connection
     $dbn = adodbConnect();

     foreach($array_result as $possible){

    //query the results
    $querys= "select * from taxonomic_units where tsn = $possible";
    $resultss = $dbn -> Execute($querys);

    while($rowss=$resultss->FetchRow()){

        $id = $rowss['tsn']; //there ID
        $ranksss = $rowss['rank_id']; //ranking id, I choose 220 and 230



            if($ranksss == 220 || $ranksss == 230){
                $prelimary_array[] = $id;

            }
        }


   //grab random index
   $index = array_rand($prelimary_array,1);

   //put result id into a variable 
   $newspecies = $prelimary_array[$index];

   //put that variable in an array
    $results_array[] = $newspecies; //there is 7 newspecies/winners at the end, I dont want duplicates
 }

  return $results_array;
}
```

Comment: there is now easy way to this this. you can try using group by in your query select * from taxonomic_units where tsn = $possible group by tsn. or group by some other coulmn .

Comment: Alter your mysql query to select distinct or group by

Comment: Use Mysql's `DISTINCT`

Comment: think this code was written by sssnakessss

Answer (score 0):

MySQL should be the following :

```
select distinct tsn, rank_id from taxonomic_units where tsn = $possible
```

But you should ideally use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

what about this? You may do it with one query:

```
$querys= "select DISTINCT tsn from taxonomic_units where tsn IN (".implode(",",$array_result).") AND rank_id IN (220,230) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop your result array and if it does not exists add it. If you end up with less than 7, do your big loop again.

replace this line :

```
$results_array[] = $newspecies;
```

by:

```
$loop_1_more_time=0;
if (isset($results_array)){
    foreach($results_array as $result){
        if ($result == $new_specie){
            $loop_1_more_time=1;
        }
    }
}
if ($loop_1_more_time == 0){
    $results_array[] = $newspecies;
}
```

//there, if $loop_1_more_time equals 1, start again. To start again and be sure you have seven instead of 6 or less, You could replace your big first "foreach" loop with a "for" loop that depends of the count() of the $array_result, and the $array_result would be array_result[$i] instead of $possible. $i would start at 0 and increment at each end of loop. It would not be incremented if ­­$loop_1_more_time==1;.
Example :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_result); $i++) {
    //stuff
    //if ($loop_1_more_time=1;) { $i--; }
}
```

Comment: hey I get an infinte loop everything I tried your solution, can you help me please. I implemented it verbatim

Comment: *note that your array that you count at the start must be non-associative. What you report can be done to the fact that you just can't have 7 possible different elements in each loop, even if it restart, so the loop gets infinite and search for a new element forever while there is not.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try shuffling the array, and then picking the first X numbers?

That way, rather than having to check the results array for duplicates, it will never come up in the first place

Comment: There could be 10 duplicates though, which could end up on the top of the array after shuffling